# Internationalization of Blog Posts

Tags: plugins, posts, multisite, localization

I have 4 domains all pointing to the same server with a server alias. They are like australia.com, america.com, china.com etc. So i have a domain for a couple of countries. I run a WordPress blog, but now I want to show certain blog posts on certain locale's or domains so to speak. Like the Americans wouldn't want to know about the things happening in Australia and vise versa.

Is there a plugin to do this?

I was thinking to just code a little block in the backend, witch check boxes with each domain, then when i generate the page, i just do an if statement on the $_SERVER array's. My only problem is i need todo this everywhere, sidebars, sitemaps etc, or is there a better solution?

Comment: Consider a Network install. One subdomain for each site. Then link your individual domains to the subdomains.

Comment: @kaiser issue is that, we dont have multiple sub domains, they are multiple domains.

Comment: I was talking about Network-Subdomain install. You can as well use a subdirectory install. Just point your TLDs to your single Network sites.

Comment: Or then use WPML, the plugin has a subdomain configuration if you will have the same information in each domain. Also it plays cool with Woocommerce, Advanced Custom Fields or Gravity forms (that are one of the most popular plugins around).